# Set PyQt window to be at the 'absolute' top level

Tags: python, linux, pyqt

With the following code I'm able to make a splash screen using PyQt with a simple message, and set it as a top level window:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import (QTime, QTimer, Qt, SIGNAL)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QLabel)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

message = 'hello'

label = QLabel("<font color=red size=72><b>{0}</b></font>"
               .format(message))
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
label.show()
QTimer.singleShot(30000, app.quit) #six seconds 
app.exec_()
```

And this generally works well.

However, when a Firefox window streaming Netflix content is made full screen, this overrides the top level defined attribute on the splash screen, and it moves the background.

Is there a way to override any other system full screen settings, so that the PyQt window is at the 'absolute' top level?

Comment: Maybe with `label.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QT.X11BypassWindowManagerHint);`

Comment: Your suggestion worked, thank you.